# Doubt of wavelets about the return of comand plot() of package Wavethresh in R language

Tags: plotting, r, wavelet

I take a plot of father wavelet with this code

```
library(wavethresh)
y <- c(1,1,7,9,2,8,8,6)
ywd <- wd(y, filter.number=1, family='DaubExPhase')
plot(ywd)
```

[image]

But the terminal returns:

```
7 7 7
```

what this `7 7 7` mean?

I try to search in the documentation ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wavethresh/wavethresh.pdf)) but without success.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a question probably better asked on the forums specific to this software.

Comment: Agreed package maintainers for wavethresh would be more qualified to answer this question